# Free google play IAP plugins for Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

Does anyone here know a good free IAP plugin for android? I'm trying to use sdkbox's one but there's no response from the application even though everything is well set-up...

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try this?
https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB-Unity-Plugin

Comment: MobiShop: This is not free (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/63636), however We got it for free though since we were beta testing it. They're currently looking for people to test some  new functionality according to the forums so maybe you can write them and get one for free if you test their newest features.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Soomla Unity IAP plugin. It's free and used by thousands of developers:
https://github.com/soomla/unity3d-store/wiki/Unity3D-IAP-Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

To me, Unity's own plugin is the one that is easiest to implement:
https://unity3d.com/services/analytics/iap